# Why is Ruby's Array#count unreliable for large arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm iterating over a combination of 2 elements of a fairly large array. When counting the elements of the combination, I found something odd. The following example shows what I mean:

```
[1] pry(main)> 10000.times.to_a.combination(2).count
=> 49995000   # correct

[2] pry(main)> 100000.times.to_a.combination(2).count
=> 704982704  # wrong, should be 4999950000

[3] pry(main)> count = 0; 100000.times.to_a.combination(2).each { count+=1 }; count
=> 4999950000 # correct
```

I double-checked the results using wolframalpha:

- pairs from 10000 entries https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000!%2F((10000-2)!*2!)
- pairs from 100000 entries https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100000!%2F((100000-2)!*2!)

**My question really is, why `Array#count` is not reliable in this case?**

Also, see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination and https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like integer overflow. Int32 unsigned max 4294967295 + 704982704 = 4999950000 (give or take 1 wherever the zero lands)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array#count` isn't the buggy method, `Enumerator#count` is:

```
100000.times.to_a.combination(2).class # => Enumerator
```

The good news is the bug you're experiencing was reported a few months ago as [#14805](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14805) and subsequently fixed but the bad news is since then no new version of CRuby was released. So either wait for 2.5.2, 2.4.5, etc. or compile a version with the fix by yourself.

The issue is the counter of an enumerator was limited to a signed 32-bit integer, so an overflow occurred:

```
max = (1 << 31) - 1 # max value
4999950000 & max    # => 704982704
```

It was fixed by making the counter a bignum (Ruby's arbitrary precision integer type, since 2.4 an internal implementation detail) in case its value would be out of bounds of an `int` or as of now an `unsigned long`.